# Are there just as many questions posted on ELL that should be on ELU?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about [changing the site name](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4692/has-anyone-thought-about-changing-the-name-of-this-site?noredirect=1#comment15830_4692).  So I am also wondering if there are questions on ELL that are really ELU questions - or as many compared to the ELL questions that appear on ELU.  I am not really on there so I would like to know if the confusion swings both ways.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at ELL's meta?

Comment: @MattЭллен - I think it could be asked on either.  I am on this stack so asked here.  Really needs to be answered by those that use both sites - so we see their perspective.

Comment: Take a look.  What do you see?  My guess is you wouldn't want most of ELL's questions over here.